# why should i use telerik radcontrols over visual studio built-in controls?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-mvc

why should i use telerik radcontrols over visual studio built-in controls. Basically i want to know the pros and cons of telerik controls.
I am new in telerik. I really get very less time for learn something new.
So is it worthwhile to choose telerik over other new technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use Telerik a lot, togheter with the standard set of controls.

**Pros**

- Prevents you from reinventing the wheel. For example, RadScheduleView and their charts are powerful, *if you need them*.
- Tons of controls, for almost any need
- Look and feel-consistency
- The huge library of [demos and examples](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/) provide a solid base when you want to rapidly do or test something
- Extensive [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/introduction.html)
- Great support from the staff and community on their forums
- Widely used - almost every issue encountered has an answer
- Quite good MVVM-support

**Cons**

- Some controls are sub par performance wise, but it has gotten better over the last few years
- You probably wont use most controls
- Your application tends to get rather large (even  with optimizations)
- The learning curve for some of the most useful controls can be steep, depending on the experience you have
- Customization of some of the controls is cumbersome
- Some controls don't offer much above the standard ones

My tip is to find out what you want to do, and check if they have a control that seems to make the cut - and try it!

Answer (score 3):

**Advantages:**

1. By using this control our lots of coding is reduced. For ex:- Telrik Grid automatically handled Pagging,Filter,Sorting...etc. So, we can reduced development time.
2. Using telerik style builder, we can easily create our custom theme to match our site theme.
3. Any .net developer get good hand on this control in very short time.
4. We can get easily support from telerik team, telerik mvp and telerik users.
5. In trail demo all the features is available, so we can implement this controls in our page and check the how it looks and match our requirement.
6. Demos and documents available in live. If internet is not available in our system then we can also install this demo in our system and we can check it offline.
7. The number of control is very high so after buying this control we do not need to buy any other control.
8. In-addition its controls also provide client side events and api.

Comment: I have once used DevExpress Grid control. check - http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Default.aspx. Is there any performance/features difference between DevExpress and Telerik Grid Control ???

Comment: I do not have idea about the devexpress control. Telerik Grid support the Client side binding, So you can achieve performance by using this method. For more info please check below link. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/declarativedatabinding/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

RadControls is a complete ASP.NET AJAX development toolset .It includes more than 70 versatile and **performance-optimized** components that help you build high-quality, professional line-of-business projects. RadControls **speed up** UI development up to 5 times and allow web developers to focus most of their time on implementing **business logic**.

Comment: I have already read it on telerik website. 
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx

I am looking for some real example.